# eclipse-dark and Ambiance-dark - how to change background color of current line

Tags: themes, eclipse, gtk, ambiance

I'm trying to use the Dark theme with eclipse and the results are pretty cool. However,  as you can see from the image below (last line starting with ObjectMapper), it is pretty difficult to read the text of the currently selected line: the background color is a shade of white/grey, very similar to the color of some of the text.
[image: Ubuntu Ambiance-dark + Eclipse Dark]

I think this bad background color is setted by the Ambiance-dark theme, which is my default GTK theme on ubuntu.
So, I'd like to use Ambiance-dark theme on Ubuntu and Dark-theme on eclipse, but I'd like to change the default background color of the selected line. Is there any way to change this color in eclipse only? Or, if it's not possible, is there any way to change it in Ubuntu? Another workaround?

I also tried tried to use the GTK theme in eclipse, but it sucks compared to the dark theme.
[image: Ubuntu Ambiance-Dark + Eclipse GTK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved thanks to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9170086/2326627

"Window - Preferences"

on the left side:

"General - Editors - Text Editors"

on the right side bottom ("Appearance color options"):

"Current line highlight"